# In mustache template how to access a key if its number from JSON response?

Tags: javascript, json, node-red

```
{
"batchcomplete": "",
"query": {
    "normalized": [{
        "from": "india",
        "to": "India"
    }],
    "pages": {
        "14533": {
            "pageid": 14533,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "India",
            "extract": "India, officially the Republic of India (Bh\u0101rat Ga\u1e47ar\u0101jya), is a country in South Asia. It is the seventh-largest country by area, the second-most populous country (with over 1.2 billion people), and the most populous democracy in the world. It is bounded by the Indian Ocean on the south, the Arabian Sea on the southwest, and the Bay of Bengal on the southeast."
        }
    }
}
}
```

In the above json response "14533" is a page id.For each trigger of an api that pageid will change.I want to access that number dynamically in "mustache template" in node-red.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. Parsing the JSON and then getting the key inside pages object

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{"batchcomplete": "","query": {"normalized": [{    "from": "india","to": "India"}],"pages": {"14533": {"pageid": 14533,        "ns": 0,    "title": "India", "extract": "India, officially the Republic of India (Bh\u0101rat Ga\u1e47ar\u0101jya), is a country in South Asia. It is the seventh-largest country by area, the second-most populous country (with over 1.2 billion people), and the most populous democracy in the world. It is bounded by the Indian Ocean on the south, the Arabian Sea on the southwest, and the Bay of Bengal on the southeast."}}}}'); 
console.log(Object.keys(obj.query.pages)[0]);
```